# How to catch the moments when path is drawn for every point in shape layer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

All I do is:

```
let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func drawBezierPath(from points: [CGPoint]) {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: points.first!)
    points.forEach { path.addLine(to: $0) }
    pathLayer.path = path.cgPath

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(block)
    let strokeEndAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    strokeEndAnimation.fromValue = 0
    strokeEndAnimation.toValue = 1
    let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
    animation.animations = [strokeEndAnimation]
    animation.duration = 1
    pathLayer.add(animation, forKey: "PathAnimation")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

The question is how to catch the moments when path is placed on the screen for every point of path. Why? I need to center scroll view to the current point. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you just add a second animation with the same path and animate the scrollview position based on the same animation?

Comment: The second animation with the same path?;) Where to add that animation?;)